# Differentiating assemblies by publicKeyToken alone

Tags: versioning, .net-assembly, strongname, extensibility, assembly-resolution

### Consider the following scenario:

1. A NuGet package contains two versions of an assembly, one for .NET 3.5 (in **lib/net35**) and one for .NET 4.0 (in **lib/net40**). Both are named **SomeInterfaces.dll** and have version **1.0.0.0**, but the strong names for the two assemblies have different `publicKeyToken` values.
2. An application named **CoolProgram.exe** exists, and exposes extensibility features (e.g. via MEF)
3. Company *A* develops an extension **AExtension.dll** and references the .NET 3.5 version of **SomeInterfaces.dll**.
4. Company *B* develops an extension **BExtension.dll** and references the .NET 4.0 version of **SomeInterfaces.dll**.
5. One of the following is provided:

   1. The extensions **AExtension.dll** and **BExtension.dll** are placed in the same folder as **CoolProgram.exe**, and the two copies of **SomeInterfaces.dll** are placed in the GAC.
   2. The application adds the paths where extensions are installed to the CLR binding path. For example, **AExtension.dll** and **SomeInterfaces.dll** (.NET 3.5) could be placed in the directory **extensions/A**, and **BExtension.dll** and **SomeInterfaces.dll** could be placed in the directory **extensions/B**; both of these two directories are placed in the binding path of the application **CoolProgram.exe**.

### Questions:

1. In situation 5.1:

   1. Will **CoolProgram.exe** be able to load **AExtension.dll** and **BExtension.dll** without any problems due to them referencing two assemblies that only differ by their `publicKeyToken`?
   2. Does the order in which the extensions are loaded make a difference?
   3. Does the answer change if **CoolProgram.exe** does not have a strong name, but both **AExtension.dll** and **BExtension.dll** do have strong names?
2. The same as question 1, but applied to situation 5.2.

### Optional Background Information:

If two assemblies are compatible at runtime; i.e. they expose the same public API and only differ in their implementation (e.g. one restricted to .NET 3.5 for the implementation and one using .NET 4.0 types in the private implementation code), then users will not face assembly binding problems in extensible applications even if the two assemblies have exactly the same strong name. This is not the case for situations where the public API differs in some way.

One solution to the case where the public API differs is to use separate names for each version of an assembly. This could lead to cases like the following for the ANTLR 4 Runtime:

- Antlr4.Runtime.net20.dll
- Antlr4.Runtime.net30.dll
- Antlr4.Runtime.net35.dll
- Antlr4.Runtime.net40.dll
- Antlr4.Runtime.net45.dll
- Antlr4.Runtime.portable_net40.dll
- Antlr4.Runtime.portable_net45.dll
- Antlr4.Runtime.netcore45.dll

The documentation associated with the project could be simplified if all the assemblies could be named **Antlr4.Runtime.dll**. In the case where users know they are working in an environment where multiple vendors could be providing code that references assemblies with different target frameworks but otherwise the same version, steps could be taken to ensure their assemblies can be located at runtime. A concrete example would be two Visual Studio extensions using ANTLR for syntax highlighting, one targeting Visual Studio 2010+ (using .NET 4.0), and one targeting Visual Studio 2012+ (using .NET 4.5). The [`[ProvideBindingPath]`](http://tunnelvisionlabs.github.io/vsbase/docs-master/html/69c59220-5eff-4177-a632-b7c1b4981501.htm) and/or [`[ProvideCodeBase]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh255336) attribute could be used to provide exactly the functionality described in situation 5.2.